# cannot convert from java.sql.Statement to DataBaseConnection.Statement

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-connection

i have this problem the quickfix of eclipse suggests me to add a cast for Statement for this row:

```
state=conex.createStatement();
```

and an other cast to state for this row:

```
result= state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM itshop.products");
```

in output i don't receive nothing,when i make the cast the error disappear,but i don't have any output.Can you check if i connect correctly to my mysql database?

code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Statement {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Connection conex=null;
          Statement state=null;
          ResultSet result=null;
          try
          {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              conex=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itshop","user","pass");
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try
          {
              System.out.println();
              state=conex.createStatement();
              result= state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM itshop.products");
              result.next();
              int RowCount=result.getRow();
              System.out.println("Rows Number Are:"+RowCount);
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }
}
```

and error shown when i don't make the cast for the above's row:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.sql.Statement to      DataBaseConnection.Statement
    The method executeQuery(String) is undefined for the type Statement

    at DataBaseConnection.Statement.main(Statement.java:22)
```

Comment: as a good practice, you should also consider organizing imports instead of using '*'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the name of your Class. There are two Statement class:

1. java.sql.Statement
2. DataBaseConnection.Statement

Try to declare your state variable as type of `java.sql.Statement` :

```
public class Statement {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Connection conex=null;
          java.sql.Statement state=null;
          ResultSet result=null;
          ....
          ....
      }
}
```

Otherwise rename your class something else than Statement

Comment: thank you for the answer,i have to organize well my import,anyway, do you find any error in mysql connection code?

Answer (score 0):

Your class name should not be Statement. You must change your class name or you can declare your statement object as `java.sql.Statement state = null;`